# Syntax error: right syntax to use near ' ' when creating a MySql trigger

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have a fairly complex trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_table AFTER UPDATE ON `table`
            FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
                IF NEW.value != OLD.value AND NEW.value != 0 THEN
                    IF NEW.value > 0 AND NEW.value < 100 THEN
                        UPDATE table2 SET section1_value = section1_value + NEW.value - OLD.value WHERE id = 0;
                    ELSEIF NEW.value >= 100 AND NEW.value < 1000 THEN
                        UPDATE table2 SET section2_value = section2_value + NEW.value - OLD.value WHERE id = 0;
                    ELSEIF NEW.value >= 1000 AND NEW.value < 5000 THEN
                        UPDATE table2 SET section3_value = section3_value + NEW.value - OLD.value WHERE id = 0;
                    ELSEIF NEW.value >= 5000 AND NEW.value < 10000 THEN
                        UPDATE table2 SET section4_value = section4_value + NEW.value - OLD.value WHERE id = 0;
                    ELSEIF NEW.value >= 10000 AND NEW.value < 20000 THEN
                        UPDATE table2 SET section4_value = section4_value + NEW.value - OLD.value WHERE id = 0;
                    ELSEIF NEW.value >= 20000 THEN
                        UPDATE table2 SET section6_value = section6_value + NEW.value - OLD.value WHERE id = 0;
                    END IF;
                ELSE IF NEW.value = 0 THEN
                    IF OLD.value > 0 AND OLD.value < 100 THEN
                        UPDATE table2 SET section1_count = section1_count - 1, section1_value = section1_value - OLD.value WHERE id = 0;
                    ELSEIF OLD.value >= 100 AND OLD.value < 1000 THEN
                        UPDATE table2 SET section2_count = section2_count - 1, section2_value = section2_value - OLD.value WHERE id = 0;
                    ELSEIF OLD.value >= 1000 AND OLD.value < 5000 THEN
                        UPDATE table2 SET section3_count = section3_count - 1, section3_value = section3_value - OLD.value WHERE id = 0;
                    ELSEIF OLD.value >= 5000 AND OLD.value < 10000 THEN
                        UPDATE table2 SET section4_count = section4_count - 1, section4_value = section4_value - OLD.value WHERE id = 0;
                    ELSEIF OLD.value >= 10000 AND OLD.value < 20000 THEN
                        UPDATE table2 SET section4_count = section4_count - 1, section4_value = section4_value - OLD.value WHERE id = 0;
                    ELSEIF OLD.value >= 20000 THEN
                        UPDATE table2 SET section6_count = section6_count - 1, section6_value = section6_value - OLD.value WHERE id = 0;
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            END;
```

I have a similar trigger that works correctly and i'm creating these in a Laravel migration using the `/DB::unprepared()` method, but when i try to create this one i get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 32 (SQL: <query_text>)
```

i can't get what's wrong, my guess is that it has something to do with semicolons but i can't figure out what.
Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PHPStorm, you need to add one more `END IF;` before the final `END;`

Alternatively, line 17, replace `ELSE IF` with `ELSEIF`

Comment: Oh right, i changed `ELSE IF` in `ELSEIF` and now it works, that was just a typo but an invisible one, thank you :)